# DIV Falling Off Screen In Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is my first time here, so please go easy on me. I have been doing coding at university for a couple of months now in one of my modules, and am just finishing off a project and beginning to test it on different browsers. It all runs fairly smoothly apart for one page on Internet Explorer.

On the image below, you'll see that the text that is supposed to go underneath the 'Public Observing' and 'Meetings' section shifts to the edge of the screen and falls off in Internet Explorer.

[image: Image of Chrome vs Internet Explorer Display of Website]

I've been googling for over an hour now with no luck, I was hoping some of you geniuses will be able to assist me!

Here is some of my HTML and CSS regarding those elements. Thank you very much for shedding any light on this issue!

```css
.observing {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 21%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.observingp {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 40%;
  align-content: left;
  float: left;
}

.meetings {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 21%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  margin-left: 42.5%;
  margin-top: -5%;
}

.meetingsp {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 30%;
  align-content: left;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div id="activities-info">

  <div id="public-observing">

    <h4 class="observing">Public Observing</h4>

    <p1 class="observingp">
      Public Observing takes place at ‘The New Inn’ at Eccup (LS168AU). Sessions are held regularly during most months, however they stop over Summer when the sunset is too late. Start times vary according to the sunset, and inconsistent dates are due to avoiding
      the full moon, which makes observing difficult.
      <br><br> Please dress warmly, as observing takes place on an open field. Also, ensure that all children are supervised by a responsible adult. The Society cannot be responsible for accidents on the field.
    </p1>
  </div>

  <div id="meetings">

    <h4 class="meetings">Meetings</h4>
    <p1 class="meetingsp">
      Meetings are held on the second Wednesday of each month at the Quaker Meeting House (LS29DX) between 7pm and 10pm. Meetings usually involve a lecture or presentation of an astronomical topic given by guest speakers or society members. <br><br> Informal
      meetings take place two weeks later, on Wednesdays. Here members have an opportunity to express and discuss their interests with personal presentations.
    </p1>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the html?

Comment: Please  provide a minimal, complete and verifiable code snippet.

Comment: @Swellar hey I've just had to take a screen shot of it and attach that because for some reason the site isn't registering it the way it has done for my CSS!

Answer (score -1):

i recommend to use normalize.css - it is a project to make all borwsers render pages consistently. Just include it as another css befoer your own css file and you will have silmilar results on all browsers.
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/